# Can't operate Tensorflow : setuptools outdated

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I've been trying to use Tensorflow for the first time. However, pip install tensorflow does not seem to cut it. I receive warning about setuptools being outdated. Even if I update setuptools to the proper version, I can't use Tensorflow. Below is the error code I get. Anyone had the same problem? Thanks a bunch in advance!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeremie Clouatre/PycharmProjects/calisse5/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\PycharmProjects\calisse5\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Jeremie Clouatre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

try unistalling it and install it from the eviroment you use for tf import.